# How to read a data frame as factors?

Tags: r, class, matrix, dataframe

I have a data frame stored in a file that looks like this:

```
             V1          V2      ...... V100
V1           0            1              0
V2           0            0              1
.
.
.
V1000
```

As you can see, the values in the dataframe can be only "0" or "1". When I do

```
myData<-read.table("data.txt")
```

R considers the columns to be of class "integers". I would like to modify the class of all my columns to become of class "factor". Is there an easy to do it?

Comment: Read the documentation for `?read.table` more carefully and look for the argument `colClasses`.

Comment: Before I answer, I must ask: **why**? A factor is just an integer with a character attached to it anyway.

Comment: The reason why I would to change it to factor is that I will be using Naive Bayesian Classifier. Because I have many 0s in my data, I might run into cases where the posterior probability will be 0.( which will cause problem for the Naive Bayesian Classifier). That's why I would like to change the class of all my columns into factor.

Comment: as.factor(x) should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have suggested:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, factor)
```

Comment: I never used those empty square brackets. What is the reason to use them?

Comment: It preserves the data.frame structure of the LHS. Otherwise you would need to use `data.frame` around the `lapply` call. In English I read it as:  "drop into `df[]` the values on the RHS of the `<-` assignment". You will notice that the str() of your result was not a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

As joran suggested, you can use

```
myData<-read.table("data.txt", colClasses="factor")
```